# Android 2d game collision detection

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, game-physics, physics-engine

I developed a 2d game in android studio using `SurfaceView`,
it's not complex in context of collision, just need to check collision between a moving-point and some static circles, for detect collision for one circle, I simply check `if X of the point is between circle minX and maxX && point Y is between minY and maxY of circle`.

So for checking collision in whole of the game, I repeat to check above code for all circles in each frame.

Game work so good when I have for example 10 circles, but if I add 30 circles, its FPS decrease so much and I face so much lag!

What should I do for this problem? should I use Box 2d physics ? what does it do for collision detection that games doesn't face lag problem even if there is so much objects which collide together?

Please help me with more detail, because I was wonder how a game engine work and decided to make a simple one, not only wanted to make and release a game(otherwise I could use a ready game engine).

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have circle objects but their collision boxes are rectangles?

Comment: yes , because I check if(circle.minX <= point.X <= circle.maxX && circle.minY <= point.Y <= circle.maxY), but its no matter really :) I got lag when increase number of circles @AppPhil

Comment: What kind of a map do you have? Or what type of game? Is it a sidescroller or something like that?

Comment: no its a simple game with an constant surface(map), no scrolling available. do you think my algorithm has no problem and I should check other parts of my game? Isn't consume to check above code in each frame for 30 circles  ? @AppPhil

Comment: @MehDi You need to create a binary map consisting  of circle points as 1 and other as zero then it's easy to find an object is inside or outside the circle. But, I've not understand your problem actually, do you want to prevent object go inside circle or something else ?

Comment: @SagarGautam thanks for your answer, but its not what I asked.
I got strange lag when I increase number of circles, I just check a simple code for collision! is it consume to check this code in each frame? what should I do then?

Comment: @MehDi Can you describe what actually want ? to detect object circle collision or object is inside/outside detection ?

Comment: This will happen - instead of having to check 10 collisions per frame the game now has to check 30, so the physics of the game runs thrice as slow. If the framerate is synchronised to the physics update, your game will run thrice as slow overall. Make the collision code faster, or deal with a lower number of circles. This is more of a Code Review question anyway.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury yes you're right, but how can I make collision code faster? Is it good to check collision in a separate thread asynchronous of update thread(main game loop thread) ?

Comment: Checking collisions in a separate thread is a good idea, but you have to synchronize it with your input - you'll receive marginal immediately apparent benefits, if any. Your problem is that collision processing is slower because more collisions have to be considered. Take your idea and use fewer circles, it'll be fine.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury  Use fewer circles isn't a good idea, its like change the problem instead of solve it. Do you have any idea, how game engines like Unity do it? They can process so many collisions easily. I should really solve it because my game is a simple 2D game! what if it was a complex 3D game?! I'm really curios how those engines handle these problem very nice!

Comment: @MehDi is your code open-source? Could you post a link to it on Github or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for how game engines do it, it is probably easiest to look at their source code directly, as at least one version of Unity can do it - you can find the source code of Unity [here](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity).

In your case, you could potentially trade off increased memory consumption by your app to make collision detections essentially constant-time regardless of the number of circles, as suggested by @[SagarGautam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6708661/sagar-gautam) in his comment.

What you can do to achieve this is store a 2D array of `boolean`s indicating all map pixels, setting each element to `true` if it is inside a circle (as per your previous code) or `false` otherwise. Doing this during the loading phase of the level/map should be fine, because now during rendering you can just look up the pixel coordinates in the array and see if it is inside a circle or not.

Comment: Did you know you are perfect?!!:D Thank you very much!! Your idea about using boolean map is so perfect!! I will implement it later and see the result and will accept this answer:) Thanks for link of Unity engine source, but it seems to be hard for me to understand the codes and workflow(Idk why!Are you like me?) ! I always think that other ones use some code base trick for achieve these problem, something that I don't know about programming(Am I true?), and this make me to forget using creative way for solving problems like you:)

Comment: It's not me who you have to be thankful to here - @SagarGautam's comment gave me the idea in the first place. Anyway, it's a common technique in computer science to do stuff involving space-time tradeoffs, like (naïve) mergesort and dynamic programming. As for Unity's codebase, just look for the part you need - Ctrl+F is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

In 3d game i use Colliders so check if there is any collider(mesh,box,etc.)
give tag to that objects.and identify them by tag 
Example:

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
            coll.gameObject.SendMessage("collided", 10);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but please read my question again, that's not what I asked